# Callback losing scope of containing function

Tags: javascript

I have a code like that:

```
{
    // other functions...
    myFunction: function( item, options, callback ) {
        var self = this;
        // Both item and options variables are accessible here.
        try {
            var content = this.getContent( item );
        } catch(ex) {
            // Exception handling here....
        }

        editor.saveContent( content, function() {

           // OPTIONS IS UNDEFINED HERE!
           // ITEM IS UNDEFINED HERE!

           // Callback, instead, is accessible!
           if ( callback ) { callback() };
       });

    }
}
```

Problem is that inside the `saveContent` callback, I can access the `callback` variable, while any attempt in accessing the `item`, `options` and `content` vars are unsuccessful! Why is that?

Comment: Are `items` and `options` actually defined, because you should be able to access them within that function?

Comment: How do you check that options and item are undefined?
What happens if you add `console.log(item, options)` inside the `edit.saveContent function`. It should create local `closure` making the variables item and options available.

Comment: the mentioned variables should be accessible, there is something wrong with your initial vars which are passed.

Comment: You can't access those variables in the saveContent method, that's not how lexical scoping works. only the content that was passed as the first argument can accessed. However you CAN access them if the callback RETURNS them

Comment: @DustinStiles They're perfectly accessible.  The code the OP has posted is fine on the face of it - there's must be more to it than what has been supplied.

Comment: Not at all, saveContent just executes the callback, it has no idea what references are stored in it unless they are returned. If you are referring to the callback that we pass to saveContent, then of course if has references. But I'm talking about accessing these variables inside of the actual saveContent function definition, in response to R. Oosterholt offering to console.log them inside of saveContent.

Comment: I think we are talking about different functions :p

Comment: @Andy yes, they are. The function that calls "myFunction" correctly passes them, and they are available until saveContent is called. Furthermore, the getContent function works properly and does not generate any exception. I'm wondering why "callback" is perfectly accessible, and item / options are not :(

Comment: @DustinStiles the editor.saveContent executes the callback function which is declare here. I'm not accessing the values in the Save Content method, I'm accessing ( or trying to, actually ) item and options inside the "savecontent callback".

Comment: @R.Oosterholt i'm in no need to access the item / options variable inside the SaveContent function. I need to access them inside the "saveContent" callback.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint at the entry to `myFunction` and examine the values of `item` and `options`.

Comment: @alex89x: Please show us *how* you are trying to access them. If you don't access them, they'll easily get garbage-collected and you won't see them when inspecting the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the variable you are interrested in to the callback function like this:

```
editor.saveContent( content, function() {
    if ( callback ) { callback(item, options) };
});
```

Via [javascript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), the `item` and `options` variable are available in the `saveContent` function.

Created [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7115a1d3/) to demonstrate *(see console log)*.

Comment: *the item and options variable are available in the saveContent function.* But the OP is saying that they are **not**.

Comment: they are when used inside the function because of the closure which will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work fine. But if that is really not working then try writing your code like this:

```
{
    // other functions...
    myFunction: function( item, options, callback ) {
        var self = this;
        // Store the reference in "this"
        self.item = item;
        self.options = options;
        self.callback = callback;

        // Both item and options variables are accessible here.
        try {
            self.content = this.getContent( item );
        } catch(ex) {
            // Exception handling here....
        }

        editor.saveContent( self.content, function() {

           // Use them here
           console.log(this.item, this.options, this.content);

           // Callback, instead, is accessible!
           if ( this.callback ) { this.callback() };
       }.bind(self));

    }
}
```

You have written `var content` inside the try-catch block. So it anyways can't be accessible outside the try-catch block.

Comment: If the OP code did not work, then chances are this will work anyway. Under what theory do you claim your code will work when his did not?

Comment: Yes, you are right @torazaburo. But, I just wanted him to try another solution. The chances are less that this will work if the OP code did not work.

Comment: No, `var content` will be hoisted and **is** available outside the block.

Answer (score -2):

```
editor.saveContent.call(this,content, function(){
//can access any variable defined in its parent scope
});
```